# how to get values from ListView in onItemClick and fill in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewpager

I have a `ListView` and when the user click on one item , a `ViewPager` should open with the same title.So if Item 1 was clicked on , a `ViewPager` page with the same title should open, like in the image(on the left side). Also the pages should be swipe able but they must be in the same row as the `ListView` like in the image(on the right side). How is it possible to do that? The `OnItemClick` method I have implemented already but what should I do now?

`listview` to `viewpager` screen look
[image]

**ListviewActiviy.java**

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position
,long id) {
mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
String rtitle = unescape(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("rtitle")));
Intent i = new Intent(ListviewActiviy.this, ViewpagerActivity.class);
i.putExtra("rtitle", rtitle);
i.putExtra("POS", position);
startActivity(i);
}
```

**ViewpagerActivity.java**

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.backgroundd, null);
position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("POS");
mCursor.moveToPosition(position);       
((ViewPager)collection).addView(view, ((ViewPager)collection).getChildCount() > position ? position : ((ViewPager)collection).getChildCount());     
final TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rhymeviewpagertext);
title = getIntent().getStringExtra("rtitle");
tv.setText(rtitle);
}
```

Comment: please respond my question to any one. suggest me or give me examples  brief description please.

Comment: you just need to create another `activity` having `ViewPager` and pass current item data when you using `onItemClick` in `listview`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int). You can use this method to open your view pager to the clicked page

Comment: @ArpitPrajapati is correct, but instead of pass the current item data, you should use the same dataset for both ViewPager and ListView and only pass the position of the item you want to show. This way you can swipe the ViewPager with the same dataset as the ListView.

Comment: please respond my question any one. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps

**step 1**

create new Activity with `ViewPager` like `ViewPagerActivty`

**step 2**

set `ItemClickListener` to your `ListView` and pass the clicked item position to your `ViewPagerActivty.this` using Intent

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,ViewPagerActivty.this);
        intent.putExtra("POS",position);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

**step 3**

get the `listview` clicked item position in your  `ViewPagerActivty` like this

```
int position=getIntent().getIntExtra("POS",1);
```

Now display data in your `ViewPager` based on that position

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161418/discussion-on-answer-by-nilu-how-to-get-values-from-listview-in-onitemclick-and).

Comment: position came but every time one position will be displayed. for example: select item 2 in listview this item 2 showing in viewpager next while swipe the left or right every time item 2 displayed. the position was not increment.

Comment: please respond my question